# oracle Time clock find exceptions with the given date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table  clockin date  and clockout date.

```
__________________________________________
userid | clockin_date           | clockout_date
------------------------------------------
a1     | '15.SEP.2014 09:24:36' | '16.SEP.2014 06:24:36'
b1     | '15.SEP.2014 09:00:36' | '16.SEP.2014 05:24:36'
b1     | '16.SEP.2014 09:05:36' | '16.SEP.2014 09:54:36'
b1     | '16.SEP.2014 10:24:36' | '17.SEP.2014 06:00:06'
b1     | '18.SEP.2014 09:24:36' | '18.SEP.2014 05:00:00'
-----------------------
```

i have to find the exception in the date if it exceeds the current date and mark it as two clockin:
one for 16 and other for 17th.

```
b1     | '16.SEP.2014 10:24:36' | '17.SEP.2014 06:00:36'
```

i wrote a query to find the total hours spent:

```
 SELECT userid, TRUNC(clockin), TRUNC(clockout), 
    CASE
      WHEN TRUNC(clockout) != TRUNC(clockin)
      THEN 0
      ELSE ROUND(SUM((clockout - clockin )*24 ),2)
    END totalhours
  FROM TIMECLOCK 
  GROUP BY userid, TRUNC(clockin), TRUNC(clockout)
```

i mark it as 0 total hours if its not in the same date. from this result, i need extract the range between two date , the result should be something like a pivot table, so that i can query the totalhours and find the exceptions.

```
 userid | clockin_date  | totalhours
    ------------------------------------------
    b1  | '15.SEP.2014' |  8.24
    b1  | '16.SEP.2014' |  0
    b1  | '17.SEP.2014' |  0
```

thank you for your help. please also let me know if my current logic is completely wrong and i failed to explain, i am just trying to find the exceptions in the clock in clock out time exception.

Comment: You query does not turn the bad clockout into a clockin. Your result will have columns for clockin and clockout and not just clockin. In general your attempted solution requires turning one row into two rows, which is always somewhat difficult. I believe you should solve this first (may require a union operation). Then the rest should be easy and your code is on the right track with its case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure what you mean by "i have to find the exception in the date if it exceeds the current date and mark it as two clockin: one for 16 and other for 17th.".

If you're just looking to highlight any instances where the clockin and clockouts happened on different dates and display the total hours for each bad instance then it's as simple as

```
SELECT userid
, clockin
, SUM(clockout - clockin)
FROM TIMECLOCK
WHERE TRUNC(clockin) != TRUNC(clockout)
GROUP BY userid, clockin
```

But if you want to identify bad instances and then combine their hours with good instances with the same clockin date then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT userid
, TRUNC(clockin)
, Min(clockin)
, MAX(clockout)
, Round(SUM(clockout - clockin)*24,2) Total_Hours
FROM TIMECLOCK
GROUP BY userid, TRUNC(clockin)
HAVING TRUNC(clockin) != TRUNC(MAX(clockout))
order by userid, TRUNC(clockin)
```

SqlFiddle Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ff2e/3

(I should also mention, that there seems to be an issue with the clockin/out dates that you posted in that they look like 12hr clock timestamps that should have AM/PM in the string. I made all the clockouts PM in the sqlfiddle.)

---

Expanding on my comment below, if you are looking for something like 'Highlight every time a user does not have a clock entry on an expected work day' then you can try something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88a81a/3

Comment: this query would return b1  | '16.SEP.2014' as the exception but i wanted to project 17.SEP.2014' date also as exception. since there was no clockin date entry for 17.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but see if this is closer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ff2e/14

Comment: I should note that if you want to do something like 'all days between sept 1 and sept 20 should have a clock in and out for eveyr user, so highlight the users that don't have an entry on any given day in that range', then this isn't going to do it. You'd probably need a separate table that lists all EXPECTED_WORK_DAYS and do a query that joins EXPECTED_WORK_DAYS with your LIST_OF_USERS and checks that for each day for each user that there exists a corresponding entry in TIMECLOCK. If no such entry exists then you have an exception.